# "React/Moment": durationFromNow outputs the duration in a negative format when used with a future date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime, momentjs

I am using Moment to render a duration (remaining time from now until a future date):

```
<Moment date={futureDate} durationFromNow />
```

`futureDate` could be for example "**2020-11-16T11:31:58.529311Z**".
I am getting the following output:

```
-3 weeks, 1 day, 23 hours
```

How can I get the output to show without the minus in the beginning of the string? And what's causing this?

It works fine with past dates.

Comment: That's how `durationFromNow` works by definition. Use `duration` instead and put in the current date manually.

Answer (score 0):

React-moment makes it's examples always with past dates and functions with future dates are not totally covered, but we can do it "manually", try this instead:

```
<Moment duration={new Date()} date={futureDate} />
```